# SignalR and SqlTableDependency trigger problem: no data after post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, signalr

In my ASP.NET Core project, when I add data with Ajax, I list data in success.
Also, after updating on the Detail page, I redirect to the Index page and see the data I updated here.
The codes were working properly and error-free.
Then I added SignalR and SqlTableDependency libraries to my project. I cannot do listing operations because the trigger named Sender occurs in the relevant table in the database. While I can list with Ajax, now I have to refresh the page or when I update on a page and go to Index, I have to refresh the Index page to see the updated data.
There are still no errors, everything works correctly, but I have to refresh the page constantly.

My code that worked properly before I added SignalR and SqlTableDependency,

AccountingController.cs

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetExpenseByUser()
{
    var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name);
    int id = user.Id;
    var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
    var responseMessage = await client.GetAsync($"https://localhost:7198/api/Expense/ListExpenseByUser?id={id}");
    if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var jsonData = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ResultExpenseByUserDto>>(jsonData);
        return Json(values);
    }
    return View();
}
```

Index.cshtml,

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        function listExpense() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "Get",
                url: "/Accounting/GetExpenseByUser",
                success: function (value) {
                    $("#tableExpense tbody").empty();
                    var tablerow;
                    $.each(value, (index, item) => {
                        tablerow = $("<tr/>");
                        tablerow.append(`<td><a class="fw-semibold text-primary">#${item.periodID}</a></td>`)
                        tablerow.append(`<td>${item.createUser}</td>`)
                        tablerow.append(`<td>${item.periodMonth}</td>`)
                        tablerow.append(`<td>${item.periodYear}</td>`)
                        switch (item.paymentStatus) {
                            case 9999:
                                tablerow.append(`<td><span class="badge bg-warning-transparent">Bekleniyor</span></td>`)
                                break;
                            case 9998:
                                tablerow.append(`<td><span class="badge bg-warning-transparent">Onay Sürecinde - Yönetici</span></td>`)
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                tablerow.append(`<td><span class="badge bg-warning-transparent">Ödeme Bekleniyor - Muhasebe</span></td>`)
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                tablerow.append(`<td><span class="badge bg-success-transparent">Ödeme Yapıldı</span></td>`)
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                tablerow.append(`<td><span class="badge bg-dark-transparent">Gecikmiş Ödeme</span></td>`)
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                tablerow.append(`<td><span class="badge bg-danger-transparent">İptal Edilen Ödeme</span></td>`)
                                break;
                        }
                        let formattedTotalAmount = parseFloat(item.totalAmount).toLocaleString('tr-TR', { minimumFractionDigits: 2 });
                        tablerow.append(`<td>₺${formattedTotalAmount}</td>`);
                        tablerow.append(`<td><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary-light btn-icon btn-sm"><i class="ri-eye-line"></i></a> <a href="/Accounting/ExpenseTransactions/${item.expenseID}" class="btn btn-primary-light btn-icon btn-sm"><i class="ri-send-plane-2-line"></i></a></td>`);
                        $("#tableExpense").append(tablerow);
                    });
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                }
            });
        }

        $("#btnAddExpense").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "Post",
                url: "/Accounting/Index",
                success: function () {
                    listExpense();

                    Toastify({
                        text: 'Harcama Dönemi Oluşturuldu',
                        duration: 3000,
                        gravity: "top",
                        position: 'right',
                        backgroundColor: "#4CAF50",
                        stopOnFocus: true,
                    }).showToast();
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    var errorMessage = xhr.responseJSON ? xhr.responseJSON : "Bu Döneme Ait Kayıt Bulunmaktadır";
                    Toastify({
                        text: errorMessage,
                        duration: 3000,
                        gravity: "top",
                        position: 'right',
                        backgroundColor: "#f64e60",
                        stopOnFocus: true,
                    }).showToast();
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Has anyone encountered this situation before? How do we solve this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, I am sharing the solution in case anyone has the same problem.

I was using the Task type for listing operations. While I was writing my queries and API side codes with async/await, I was using the void structure for post or put operations. In this case, there was a problem like this, I was seeing data that was not added or updated because it brought the data without waiting for the end of the post operation. The problem was solved when I used the async/await structure for Post, Put and Delete operations. Below you will see an example for both get and post operations.

I hope it helps. Have a good work.

**Get,**

```
public async Task<List<ResultExpenseByUserDto>> ListExpenseByUser(int id)
{
    string query = "SELECT TOP(12) E.ExpenseID, U.Name + ' ' + U.Surname AS CreateUser, E.PeriodMonth, E.PeriodYear, E.PaymentStatus, E.TotalAmount, E.Status, E.PeriodID FROM Expense E INNER JOIN AspNetUsers U ON E.CreateUser = U.Id WHERE E.CreateUser = @createUser ORDER BY E.ExpenseID DESC";
    var parameter = new DynamicParameters();
    parameter.Add("@createUser", id);
    using (var connection = _dapperContext.CreateConnection())
    {
        var values = await connection.QueryAsync<ResultExpenseByUserDto>(query, parameter);
        return values.ToList();
    }
}
```

**Post,**

```
public async Task itemAddExpense(CreateExpenseDto createExpenseDto)
{
    string query = "INSERT INTO Expense (CreateUser, PeriodMonth, PeriodYear, PeriodID) values (@createUser, @periodMonth, @periodYear, @periodID)";
    var parameter = new DynamicParameters();
    parameter.Add("@createUser", createExpenseDto.CreateUser);
    parameter.Add("@periodMonth", createExpenseDto.PeriodMonth);
    parameter.Add("@periodYear", createExpenseDto.PeriodYear);
    parameter.Add("@periodID", createExpenseDto.PeriodID);
    using (var connection = _dapperContext.CreateConnection())
    {
        await connection.ExecuteAsync(query, parameter);
    }
}
```

**API Controller Side,**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> AddExpense(CreateExpenseDto createExpenseDto)
{
    if (await _expenseService.itemIsExpenseDuplicate(createExpenseDto))
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        await _expenseService.itemAddExpense(createExpenseDto);
        return Ok("Başarılı");
    }
}
```

When I get an error
"*_expenseService.itemAddExpense(createExpenseDto);*"
I was not using the await structure in the line.